# SSH paramiko error Python

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm trying to connect to a client with SSH and exectute command. This is my Client code

```
import paramiko
import threading

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', username = 'user', password = 'pass')
client_transport = client.get_transport()
chan = client_transport.open_session()
print("casa")
chan.send("Ce sto!")
print(chan.recv(1024))

client.close()
```

And this is the error that gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Client.py", line 9, in <module>
    chan = client_transport.open_session()
  File "/home/leonardo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 702, in open_session
    timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/leonardo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 823, in open_channel
    raise e
EOFError
```

What could be the problem?
Thanks

Comment: does the host exists and is reachable by your computer? I think that it might result in a timeout, that's why I ask

Comment: They are connected on the same network, how can I check if is reachable?

Comment: send a ping at that host

Comment: I checked and the client can reach the server and the opposite

Comment: Can you ssh to it via terminal?

Comment: Yes, but after I'm connected it says        Connection to 192.168.1.XX closed by remote host.
Connection to 192.168.1.XX closed.

Comment: so it is problem on the server and not in your code. Investigate the other side.